# About glm quaternions calculation

Tags: c++, quaternions, glm-math, euler-angles

I am having issue understanding the glm framework. I have this piece of code where I convert an input quaternion to euler angles and back to the quaternion using the obtained euler angles. Shouldn't the two quats be same ? But it seems they are different.

```
glm::fquat inputQuat(0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.31);
glm::vec3 eulers = glm::eulerAngles(inputQuat);
glm::fquat antiQuat = glm::fquat(glm::vec3(eulers.x, eulers.y, eulers.z));
```

The value of antiQuat is `{x=0.659721971 y=0.310936451 z=0.381391585 w=0.568001628}`

This seems like something I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: Note that your input quaternion is not a unit quaternion, i.e. it isn't of length 1. Thus, it doesn't actually represent a rotation, which might explain your problem.